# Why g++ not link static programs?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, g++

I installed Ubuntu 17.04 
them:

```
apt-get install libsdl2-dev`
```

and all extras
when I compiled program by:

```
g++ -o prg main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx -lSDL2_image
```

application work only in terminal by

```
./prg
```

but in Ubuntu interface i see window "there is no program to open files shared library" what i must do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Comment: Start by posting a [mcve] along with all relevant error messages (*verbatim*) along with a description of what you've tried an what you have researched in your attempt to find a solution. As it stands, your question is unanswerable.

Answer (score 1):

In Ubuntu 17.04 the GCC toolchains have been configured - for the first time
in Ubuntu - to generate PIE (Position Independent Executable) code by default.

If you compile your program in verbose mode - `g++ -v ...` - and capture the output,
there you will see:

```
Configured with: ... --enable-default-pie ...
```

which is not so on earlier releases.

This means that *programs* are now relocatable binaries, as shared libraries
have always been. You can check this definitively with the `file` command on your `prg`:

```
$ file prg
prg: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64,...
```

As a result, the graphical file manager is no longer able to
distinguish programs from shared libraries just by examining them and when asked to open a program
you have built yourself thinks that you want to open a shared library, which it doesn't know how to do. Perhaps
in future the file manager will be enabled to tell the difference between
a shared library and a PIE program, but until then you will have to run your
programs by opening a terminal for the purpose.

I do not know the motivation for this toolchain change but I would
speculate that it is because PIEs can benefit from [ASLR - Address Space Layout Randomization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization) - an established exploit-mitigation defense that has been enabled in Ubuntu, and Linux generally, for a long time but from which
program executables are exempt, unless compiled as PIE.

**Later**

> What i must to do to [build a] static application?

If you wish to make a non-PIE program that the file-manager can recognize as
a program and run, then add `-no-pie` to your linkage options.

```
$ g++ -no-pie -o prg main.cpp -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx -lSDL2_image
```

or if you compile first and link second, then:

```
$ g++ -o main.o -c main.cpp
$ g++ -no-pie -o prg main.o -lSDL2 -lSDL2_gfx -lSDL2_image
```

Be aware, however, that a non-PIE program is not the same thing as
a *statically linked* program, and that your commandline would *never*
have produced a statically linked program. You have not indicated any
reason why you would want a statically linked program, and probably don't.

Comment: What i must to do to make static application? i try -static no work

Comment: I want to build standalone exec file what i must do?

Comment: @MartinPh A PIE executable *is* a standalone executable. It is
a *relocatable* standalone executable. If you don't like
your standalone executables being relocatable, for some
reason, then add `-no-pie` to your linkage options, as
my answer explains.

Comment: @MartinPh If you want to make a program that is not linked with any shared libraries (a statically linked program) then use linkage option `-static`